# How to exclude header under current path in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

Suppose I have two directory `product` and `test`.

```
./test
./test/test_product.cpp
./test/foo.h
./product
./product/product.cpp
./product/product.h
./product/foo.h
```

And `product.cpp` include `foo.h` as:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

The default behavior is to include `/product/foo.h`.
However, I want to include `/test/foo.h` in `/product/product.cpp` without any modification in product directory.
Is there any way to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add search paths that the GCC preprocessor use to look for header files with the `-I` option, and then you could use angle-brackets when including the file, then the preprocessor should look for files in the same directory as the source file last.

In other words add e.g. `-Itest` to add the `test` directory to the include file search path. Then use `#include <foo.h>` instead. And when you want to use `product/foo.h` instead, just remove the `-Itest` option and add `-Iproduct` instead.

---

There is also another way, that involved *conditional compilation* and the [solution suggested by Lanting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127893/440558).

You could have e.g.

```
#ifdef TEST
# include "../test/foo.h"
#else
# include "foo.h"
#endif
```

Then to build with `test/foo.h` you defined the macro `TEST`, which can be done on the command line using the `-D` option:

```
$ gcc -DTEST ...
```

To use the `product/foo.h` just remove the option so `TEST` is no longer defined.

Comment: Thanks for answer it! Unfortunately, I cannot have any modification on product source code. So Is there any other way I can do?

Comment: @walker the method provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164874/2422450 doesn't modify the source (but involves some rather complicated messing with precompiled headers)

Answer (score 0):

You're free to add full and relative paths to headers in includes.

```
#include "../test/foo.h"
```

would, for instance, work

Have a look at these discussions on how and when to use which include form: [What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-relative-path-such-as-include-header-h-for-a-hea)
and 
[How to use #include directive correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464560/how-to-use-include-directive-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can include headers in the file by providing its path under #include.
 ex.
 #include "path to .h file"

Answer (score 0):

you can use the header guard to archive that, assuming that both files are having different header guard, 
you can add -D(header guard of whichever file you do not want) in the list of flags in the make file.